# Solving functional equations with antiderivatives as input : $f(F^{-1}(x)) = 1 - \frac{1}{f(x)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I want to solve below equation by relation $F(x) =\int{f(x)}$, where $F^{-1}(x)$ is $F(x)$'s inverse function.

$$f(F^{-1}(x)) = 1 - \frac{1}{f(x)}$$

$f(x)$ is probably not an elementary function. Is there a general approach to determining the features of these function? Maybe it is a fairly naive relation to get the function itself, so it's okay to get only the constraints on the function.

- Input of antiderivative is also same as input of original function, because of it is $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}$ function.
- Also this equation can be reduced into ordinary differential equation form,

$$f'(x) = f(x)(1-f(x))^2 f'(f^{-1}(\frac{1}{1-f(x)}))$$

Comment: Where'd you come across this problem?

Comment: @EliBartlett It's come from price-action curve of some specialized decentralized AMM system

Comment: Here's a solution I arrived at by guessing and also via the following: 
\begin{align}
F'(F^{-1}(x))+\frac{1}{F'(x)}=1.
\end{align}
Define the inverse of $F(x)$ as $V(x)$, then
\begin{align}
V'(V(x))+\frac{1}{V'(x)}=1.
\end{align}
For $F'(x)=V'(x)\rightarrow F(F(x))=x-\tau$, for some constant $\tau$.

We then obtain the functional equation 
\begin{align}
f(x-\tau)=1-\frac{1}{f(x)}.
\end{align}

Comment: (...) I have found the family of solutions
\begin{align}
f(x)=\frac{\varphi C+e^{rx}}{C+\varphi e^{rx}},
\end{align}
where $\varphi$ is a solution to $\varphi^2-\varphi+1=0$, $C$ is an arbitrary constant and $r$ relates to $\tau$. For $C=0$, $f(x)\equiv\varphi$, which is easily checked in the original equation, but for $C\neq0$ I am having trouble seeing if this truly solves the original equation.

Comment: @EliBartlett Maybe your first comment's last term wrong, as input's F - rank difference of two f - term have to be form 2k+1, like $f(F^{-1}(x))$ and $f(x)$, since $F(F(x)) = x - \tau$ only guarantees that multiple of 2 rank difference of input reduced into constant difference

Comment: @EliBartlett More simply, if $f(F^{-1}(x)) = f(x-\tau)$ is true then $F^{-1}(x) = x - \tau$, so $F(x) = x + \tau$, $f(x) = 1$, which makes no sense..